# how can i implement onmouseover for my chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

i want to implement a bitcoin price chart using googleCharts, if you search for bitcoin price on google you gonna see the below chart in top of google search page 
[image: google bitcoin price chart]

when you hover on chart , no matter where, it displays a price corresponding to a row and a column , but default behavior  of google area chart is not like that and you have to hover on result line itself like below image
[image: my price chart]

so, how can i implement a chart like the first image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to set the focus onmouseover, its mentioned in the google chart documentation, 
In your case you use option **focustarget**  with set to "category". 
Here is a working example of what you are looking for.

```
 var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0},
      focusTarget: 'category'
    };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tjc2honu/